# Eclipse project configuration JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

My Eclipse Neon is well setted with Java 8 , my project maven is also setted with java 8 , when i tried to did some advanced instruction like lambda expression or even a multi exception try catch i got the following error:

as an exple for multi-catch / lambda:

> statement is not supported in -source 1.5

I don't know why when building the project with maven  gave me this error.

Is like the IDE consider the JVM in version 1.5?

Any idea how can i deal with this issue.

Comment: Maven by default uses the source level 1.5. [See here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for how to change it to 1.8.

Comment: it works now ..